# getting parse error in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data to server and get back some data in json format using ajax, what i've tried

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['data1'])) {
       $dt = $_REQUEST['data1'];
       $arr = [1,2,3];
       header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
       echo json_encode($arr);
 }
```

```js
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
             jQuery('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
             jQuery('#datepick').datepicker({
                    format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
             });
             jQuery('.client_list a').click(function() {
                alert(jQuery(this).text()); 
                var data={};
                data['client_name']=jQuery(this).text();
                load_data(data,window.location.pathname);
             });
         });
        var load_data=function(data,url,selector){
            jQuery.post(url,{'data1':data})
            .done(function(result){
                console.log(result+"Hello");
            })
            .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus) {
                console.log( "failed due:"+ textStatus);
            });
        };
    </script>
```

I'm getting parseerror why is is this

**UPDATE**
my php script and jquery are in one file and my url is window.location.pathname inside getJSON

Answer (score 0):

When jQuery receives a JSON response from an AJAX request it will *automatically* deserialise it for you. The error you're seeing is because you're calling `parseJSON` on an object, you just need to remove that call:

```
jQuery.getJSON(url,{'data1':data})
    .done(function(result){
        console.log(result + "Hello");
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log( "failed due:"+ textStatus);
    });
```

Comment: still facing same error after removing the parseJSON

Comment: my php script and jquery are in one file and my url is window.location.pathname inside getJSON

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['data1'])) {

    $dt = $_REQUEST['data1'];
    $arr = [1,2,3];
    header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

change your code because you are sending data by using get method and receiving through post.

Javascript

```
console.log(data);
jQuery.getJSON(url,{'data1':data})
    .done(function(result){
        console.log(result + "Hello");
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log( "failed due:"+ textStatus);
    });
```

IN your console check data is not null by updating this code.

Comment: Have you change your condition from $_POST to $_REQUEST ?

Comment: update your javascirpt code and check data variable should not be empty.